# How to implemet isTimerRunning() for this class

Tags: java, timertask

I have this code, which basically provides a custom timer for my application.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class SMSFirewallTimer {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SMSFirewallTimer.class);
    Timer timer;
    String timerId;

    public SMSFirewallTimer(int seconds, String string) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timerId = string;
        logger.debug("SMSFirewallTimer: timer started for: "+seconds +"seconds");
        timer.schedule(new Timeout(string), seconds*1000);
    }

    public void cancelTimer()
    {
        this.timer.cancel();
        logger.debug("SMSFirewallTimer: Cancelling timer for : " + this.timerId);
    }

    class Timeout extends TimerTask {
        private String string;
        public Timeout(String string) {
            this.string = string;

        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            logger.debug("SMSFirewallTimer: Time's up! for: " + this.string );
            timer.cancel(); //Terminate the timer thread            
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem arises that I want a `isRunning()` method in `SMSFirewallTimer` which will tell me that if the timer is still running or not, and it should also keep timeout in mind.

If I just declare a boolean as `isTimer` in this class it only holds good if we use `cancelTimer()`, but it wont come to know if timer expired, as its another scheduled method `new Timeout(string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Timeout` is an inner class of `SMSFirewallTimer` which means that each instance of `SMSFirewallTimer` is tied to a specific instance of `SMSFirewallTimer` and that is has access to its fields and methods.

It should be sufficient to replace:

```
        timer.cancel(); //Terminate the timer thread
```

with

```
        cancelTimer(); //Terminate the timer thread
```

in the `run` method of `Timeout`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class SMSFirewallTimer {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SMSFirewallTimer.class);
    Timer timer;
    String timerId;
    private Boolean isRunning;


    public SMSFirewallTimer(int seconds, String string) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timerId = string;
        logger.debug("SMSFirewallTimer: timer started for: "+seconds +"seconds");
        isRunning = true;
        timer.schedule(new Timeout(string), seconds*1000);
    }

    public void cancelTimer()
    {
        isRunning = false;
        this.timer.cancel();
        logger.debug("SMSFirewallTimer: Cancelling timer for : " + this.timerId);
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }


    class Timeout extends TimerTask {
        private String string;
        public Timeout(String string) {
            this.string = string;

        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            logger.debug("SMSFirewallTimer: Time's up! for: " + this.string );
            isRunning = false;
            timer.cancel(); //Terminate the timer thread            
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can keep reference for Timeout if you don't want to have access from your Timeout to your SMSFirewallTimer isRunning field.